# Using CATransition to custom viewcontroller transition animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have two viewcontroller A and B. A support portrait and landscape, B only support portrait.The below codes are on A.

```
UIStoryboard *board = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
B *vcb = [board instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"B"];

CATransition *a=[CATransition animation];
a.duration = 0.4f;
a.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
a.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
a.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
[self.view.window.layer addAnimation:a forKey:@"kTransitionAnimation"];
[self presentViewController:vcb animated:NO completion:nil];
```

And on B ,i do the dissmiss.

```
CATransition *a=[CATransition animation];
a.duration = 0.4f;
a.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
a.type = kCATransitionReveal;
a.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;

[self.view.window.layer addAnimation:a forKey:@"dismiss"];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

It works ok on portrait mode. But it works wrong when i do the bellow steps:
1. Present the B on portrait mode
2. Turn the cellphone to landscape and then click to dissmiss B.
3. The animation was wrong.
Can anybody explain this and how to fix it.I want the B act same as on the portrait mode.

Comment: Why you are adding animation in present model, you are just doing kCATransitionFromTop and kCATransitionFromBottom this is the by default animation in that.

Comment: It's just a demo. So the direction of this animation maybe kCATransitionFromLeft or kCATransitionFromRight. The point is why the animation wrong the i turn the cellphone to landscape. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, I understand your question correctly. Probably you should handle the DeviceOrientation in your Controller A.